# mariadb can't connect to server remotely

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb

This is my first time trying to create an sql server that can be accessed remotely by a user. I believe I have set this up correctly but am unable to connect to my server remotely.

### Issue

When I run `sudo mysql -u user1 -h <google vm external ip address> -p` I get the below error after entering my password

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '<google vm external ip address>' (11 "Resource temporarily unavailable")
```

I've tried to find out what might be the cause of this but only seem to find articles relating to the server being offline (which it's not) or steps on how to do the set up I've already done so far. If anyone has any further steps I might be able to check it would be appreciated.

### Setup

- Running on a ubuntu 18.04 LTS Google VM
- Below is the output of \s on the Mariadb database:

> ```
> mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.44-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
>
> Connection id:          33
> Current database:
> Current user:           root@localhost
> SSL:                    Not in use
> Current pager:          stdout
> Using outfile:          ''
> Using delimiter:        ;
> Server:                 MariaDB
> Server version:         10.1.44-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu 18.04
> Protocol version:       10
> Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket
> Server characterset:    utf8mb4
> Db     characterset:    utf8mb4
> Client characterset:    utf8mb4
> Conn.  characterset:    utf8mb4
> UNIX socket:            /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
> Uptime:                 38 min 12 sec
> ```

- I set up mariadb using - https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-mariadb-on-ubuntu-18-04/
- Created a user setup as below based on my understanding that `%` would allow my user to connect from anywhere, as shown below.

> ```
> +-----------+-------+
> | host      | user  |
> +-----------+-------+
> | %         | user1 |
> | localhost | user1 |
> | localhost | root  |
> +-----------+-------+
> ```

- I've edited the `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf` file to comment out the bind address

> ```
> # Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
> # localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
> #bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First time server user... turns out google vm blocks everything coming in like mysql or postgres so you need to create an exception in the firewall rules for this.

Documentation I found helpful to set up an exclusion in the rules - https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls?authuser=1